# Foaf purpose in front of :firstName

Tags: rdf, foaf

the rdf triple  “Picasso’s first name is Pablo” as http://example.org/Picasso foaf:firstName "Pablo" Why is needed foaf, in front of :firstName?.It seems clear enough that :firstName refer to Pablo. Can ":firstName" be understood to refer to something else? It would generate an error if foaf or "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/" would be missing?

Comment: `foaf:firstName` is just the prefixed form of the URI `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/firstName` - nothing more nothing less. And `foaf` is just the prefix name for the namespace `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/` - you could also call it `ex` or just `:` in your RDF document - it doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

`foaf` (friend of a friend) is just a standard way of referring in your rdf triple which contains the predicates `firstName`/`lastName` and `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/` is the URI for that. You can, however, choose any meaningful URI to denote the `firstName`. However, please note that when your data is shared across other applications, you should use something generic which is understood and recognized by the other applications. So `foaf` would be the right choice.

Answer (score 1):

RDF is all about trying to describe resources clearly.

If you used just `firstName` (without a prefix) - as a person I can guess what you mean but as a computer it's not clear (maybe you mean the first name given to a project before the final project name is decided?).

In RDF we expect each usage to have a different URI so it is clear which type of first name is being used, e.g. `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/firstName` vs. `http://example.com/project/firstName`.

So this expanded triple says exactly the same as yours: `http://example.org/Picasso  http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/firstName  "Pablo"`

URIs are long, so it's easier for humans to use a nickname for each - this is where readable prefixes come from. You need to specify which nickname maps to which base URI.

Technically you can decide to specify that something else like `foobar` means `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/` (e.g. `foobar:firstName`), but FOAF is widely known, so most people use `foaf:firstName`.

What you have been shown on screen in your example is `foaf:firstName`, but the system that showed it to you will will somewhere have a definition of what `foaf:` actually represents, i.e. `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/`.